# Silverlight OutOfBrowser Problem

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I am developing silverlight application. I want create the out of browser application .

This is My OutOfBrowserSettings.xml

```
<OutOfBrowserSettings ShortName="CollegeManagement Application" EnableGPUAcceleration="False" ShowInstallMenuItem="True">
  <OutOfBrowserSettings.Blurb>CollegeManagement Application on your desktop; at home, at work or on the go.</OutOfBrowserSettings.Blurb>
  <OutOfBrowserSettings.WindowSettings>
    <WindowSettings Title="CollegeManagement Application" Height="300" Width="500" />
  </OutOfBrowserSettings.WindowSettings>
  <OutOfBrowserSettings.Icons />
</OutOfBrowserSettings>
```

It Installed correctly. But When I open the outofBrowser application, It Shows Blank White Page,It doesn't Show start page

please help me,

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a few minutes to read the FAQ and the Markdown documentation (a useful synposis of which is available in the right hand margin when editing a question).

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong with the settings you have posted.  The first diagnostic I would do is create a "Hello, World!" Silverlight app with these OOB settings.  Check that it runs in browser then install it as OOB.  Run the OOB, does it work?  I suspect the answer is yes.

The next place to look is the App.xaml.cs, what is happening on application start that may not be working as expected in OOB?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out the problem, I have been added  the SizeChangedEventHandler on Startup page for dynamically resizing the page.

Once I have removed SizeChangedEventHandler it is all working fine.

thank you.